# How to make dutch pannekoek?

Tags: frying, pancakes

How can I make those Dutch pannekoek, specially those salty ones that have cheese and mushrooms? Every time I try, I end up burning those "toppings".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You pour in the batter, wait for the underside to be cooked (some brown patches), flip it, then put cheese on the (browned) top. With spek (bacon), you don't need to do this, you can just put the spek into the pan, fry it until done, then pour batter over it, and proceed as normal. Dutch pancakes are fairly thin, so they don't take very long to cook. Spek won't get properly crisp if you pour the batter on it immediately, also because the watery batter cools it down. Apple pieces won't burn either, so you can put those in first (I hate those, they will make your pancake break!).

Comment: After pouring in the batter, you often need to tilt the pan to get good coverage of the pan.  (if you just poured it in and let it flow on its own, you'll end up with too thick of a pannekoek, unless you make the batter really thin, which gives you other problems later)

Comment: @Joe: Absolutely! I assumed the OP would get that...

Comment: It sounds like the original poster had some experience ... but just in case someone else stumbled upon this question, I thought it'd be good to mention.

Comment: @Joe: Sure, it can't hurt!

Comment: And just an addition - the OP asked specifically about mushrooms. Like all other things that you could put in a stir fry, it can go in at the same time you would put the bacon in.

Comment: @ErikP.: I didn't mention mushrooms because...I don't like mushrooms! I couldn't in good conscience recommend eating those monsters...

Comment: You *can* have other ingredients on the baking side as well, just make sure you do that side last (=shorter). So: batter first, ingredients on top, wait until almost done 'through', then flip and leave for a short time. That'll still give you that gratifying browning of the cheese.

Comment: And apple pieces will break your pancake less if you make thin slices; not chunks.

Comment: @JanDoggen: I do that too with cheese. But it seemed the OP didn't want the cheese to brown? As to apple slices, even thin slices weaken the pancake, and pancakes as so very thin and weak already. And thin slices add very little to the taste of the pancake. I prefer to fry my apple slices separately (in a little bit of wine, sugar, lemon juice, and cinnamon) and just put them on the pancake when it's done, before I roll it.